# How to download and install OpenVPN using C# and automate device configuration?

Tags: c#, automation, windows-installer, vpn, openvpn

I'm currently working on a C# project where I need to automate the process of downloading and installing OpenVPN on a Windows machine using an MSI file.

I've tried the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string downloadUrl = "https://swupdate.openvpn.org/community/releases/OpenVPN-2.6.4-I001-amd64.msi";
        string msiFilePath = "OpenVPN-2.6.4-I001-amd64.msi";
        string installFolderPath = ".";

        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.DownloadFile(downloadUrl, msiFilePath);
        }

        ProcessStartInfo installProcessInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("msiexec.exe", $"/i \"{msiFilePath}\" /qn INSTALLLOCATION=\"{installFolderPath}\"");
        Process installProcess = Process.Start(installProcessInfo);
        installProcess.WaitForExit();

        if (installProcess.ExitCode == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("MSI File Has Been Downloaded.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Couldn't Install MSI File.");
        }

        File.Delete(msiFilePath);
    }
}
```

However, it doesn't seem to download any executable files to the specified folder. I wanted to inquire about this issue and also gather information on how I can automate the process of configuring my device as an OpenVPN server using C#.

I would appreciate any insights, suggestions, or sample code that can help me achieve this goal. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Are you running the code as admin?

Comment: @Enigmativity Yes

Comment: Then I would use explicitly defined paths. for both the download and the execution of the exe.